# How to write a for loop that iterates a certain number of times: Coral

Tags: google-coral

Write a for loop that iterates numPluses times. Each iteration: Put "+" to output.

Ex: If input is 4, then output is:

++++

This is what I have so far:

```
integer numPluses
integer userNum
integer i

// Program will be tested with inputs: 4, 6 and -1
numPluses = Get next input
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it). 
Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.
Please read [How to Ask Homework Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and come back to [edit] your question and improve it.

Comment: How is this question related to google-coral ?